# How to force SMTPClient to authenticate

Tags: c#, .net, smtp

I have a smtp server that does not require authentication for sending emails, I use C#'s SmtpClient:

```
        message.From = new MailAddress(appSettings.senderMail);      
        message.Subject = appSettings.mailsubj;
        message.Body = appSettings.mailbody;
        Attachment attach = new Attachment(sOutput);
        message.Attachments.Add(attach);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(appSettings.SMTP, appSettings.smtpSvPort);
        if (bSMTPAuth)
        {
            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(strSMTPUsername, strSMTPPAssword);
        }

        client.SendCompleted += this.SendCompletedCallback;
            message.To.Clear();
            message.To.Add(clientEmail);
            client.Send(message);
```

And it works to send without authentication, but when I try to authenticate, even if I use incorrect password, the mail still gets sent, I want to see if the authentication works.. and throw and error when I connect with wrong user/password.

Comment: Pretty sure that is a requirement you need to deal with on the mail server, rather than the client end.

Comment: You are right, I've tried using gmail.. not toio much luck in that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19730641/mscorlib-input-string-was-not-in-a-correct-format-in-smtpclient-sendmailmessage

Comment: Not sure what else you can do then. If the server doesn't question or challenge the credentials you are sending, you're not going to get any kind of authentication issue to handle.

Comment: I've setup hMailServer on localhost, and on the SMTP>delivery of email, I've set it to "Server require authentication" & "Use SSL" even if I don't supply these parameters from within the code above it allows me to connect to the SMTP server... I don't know how to enforce to authentication delivery only

Comment: SNMP and SMTP are completely different. Please pay attention to which tags to choose in the future.